# Root locked out of SSH

Tags: ssh

I have tried to set up SFTP on a Debian machine, and was following [instructions](http://blog.markvdb.be/2009/01/sftp-on-ubuntu-and-debian-in-9-easy.html) (and [here](http://ipggi.wordpress.com/2011/06/29/implement-a-sftp-service-for-ubuntudebian-with-a-chrooted-isolated-file-directory/)) to prevent SFTP users from using remote login too.

But in doing so, it seems like I have locked root out from remote login too. Of course, without remote login, it seems like I am unable to fix this. It doesn't look like telnet is enabled. My other, ftp only, users are chrooted.

Is there any way to fix this? I guess if I were able to restore my sshd_config file (backed up as /etc/ssh/sshd_config.bak), I may able to log in again, but how to gain access?

As you can tell from the nature of the question, I am a bit of a newbie at all this....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Log in with your normal user account (the one for yourself, that you *didn't* put in a chroot) and `su` to root, then you can fix the problem.

If you somehow managed to chroot your own user account, or never created one in the first place (don't *ever* repeat this mistake) then you will have to get on the console, reboot to single user mode and recover it from the console.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm afraid I don't have a normal user account, I usually just ssh in as root. So I just have root, and chrooted ftp accounts.

Comment: That's terribly bad practice; you should stop doing that now.

Comment: @tarling: Michael is right. It sounds like getting locked out is about the best thing that could happen. Root login should *never* be permitted via ssh. It's a downright shame that this is the shipped configuration in most systems.